# Finding common characters in two strings

Tags: c++, c, string

I am coding for the problem in which we got to count the number of common characters in two strings. Main part of the count goes like this

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < strlen(s2); j++) {
        if(s1[i] == s2[j]) {
            count++;
            s2[j] = '*';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This goes with an O(n^2) logic. However I could not think of a better solution than this. Can anyone help me in coding with an O(n) logic.

Comment: Can you clarify what "number of common characters" means? Perhaps what the function should return in the case ("aa", "aa"). Possible answers might be 1, 2 or 4.

Comment: it should be 2. for case like "cccc" and "ccc" it should return 3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very simple. Take two `int` arrays `freq1` and `freq2`.  Initialize all its elements to `0`. Then read your strings and store the frequencies of the characters to these arrays. After that compare the arrays `freq1` and `freq2` to find the common characters.

Comment: As there is a programming contest is going on [here](http://www.codechef.com/FEB14#rank-tab-1) and a question is asked with the similar logic, I did't included the code for it.

Answer (score 7):

It can be done in O(n) time with constant space.

The pseudo code goes like this :

```
int map1[26], map2[26];
int common_chars = 0;

for c1 in string1:
    map1[c1]++;

for c2 in string2:
    map2[c2]++;

for i in 1 to 26:
    common_chars += min(map1[i], map2[i]);
```

Comment: what  `map2[c2]++` does?

Comment: @Alex, in the second map, increases the count of character c2 by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is O(n^3) because of the O(n) `strlen`s and produces incorrect results, for example on "aa", "aa" (which your code will return 4).

This code counts letters in common (each letter being counted at most once) in O(n).

```
int common(const char *a, const char *b) {
    int table[256] = {0};
    int result = 0;
    for (; *a; a++)table[*a]++;
    for (; *b; b++)result += (table[*b]-- > 0);
    return result;
}
```

Depending on how you define "letters in common", you may have different logic. Here's some testcases for the definition I'm using (which is size of the multiset intersection).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct { const char *a, *b; int want; } cases[] = {
        {"a", "a", 1},
        {"a", "b", 0},
        {"a", "aa", 1},
        {"aa", "a", 1},
        {"ccc", "cccc", 3},
        {"aaa", "aaa", 3},
        {"abc", "cba", 3},
        {"aasa", "asad", 3},
    };
    int fail = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cases) / sizeof(*cases); i++) {
        int got = common(cases[i].a, cases[i].b);
        if (got != cases[i].want) {
            fail = 1;
            printf("common(%s, %s) = %d, want %d\n",
                   cases[i].a, cases[i].b, got, cases[i].want);
        }
    }
    return fail;
}
```

Comment: What if user enter strings `aasa` and `asad`?

Comment: I think table[*b]-- should be table[*b]

Comment: It depends how you define "letters in common".

Comment: @MustafaChelik I think you've downvoted my answer because of an ambiguity in the original question about what the result should be when there's repeated letters. I've added testcases that show that the code is doing what I expect is the right interpretation of "letters in common"

Comment: I think that topic starter's example is O(N^2) and not O(N^3).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 2n:

```
int i,j, len1 = strlen(s1), len2 = strlen(s2);
unsigned char allChars[256] = { 0 };
int count = 0;

for( i=0; i<len1; i++ )
{
    allChars[ (unsigned char) s1[i] ] = 1;
}

for( i=0; i<len2; i++ )
{
    if( allChars[ (unsigned char) s1[i] ] == 1 )
    {
        allChars[ (unsigned char) s2[i] ] = 2;
    }
}

for( i=0; i<256; i++ )
{
    if( allChars[i] == 2 )
    {
        cout << allChars[i] << endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest to test before adding some guidance and explaining it afterward. This won't work as intended

Comment: Here your mistake is `cout << allChars[i] << endl;` should print the character of the character that has the value of 2 in the index. To resolve it, you will have a variable char `c` out of the loop scope. Then your `c` must be equal to the current index, then you will want to `cout << c << endl;` You will have a new string of characters in their alphabetical order; but not in the first occurrence. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Following code traverses each sting only once. So the complexity is O(n). One of the assumptions is that the upper and lower cases are considered same.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[] = "Hello world";
    char b[] = "woowrd";
    int x[26] = {0};
    int i;
    int index;

    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        index = a[i] - 'a';
        if (index > 26) {
            //capital char
            index = a[i] - 'A';
        }
        x[index]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        index = b[i] - 'a';
        if (index > 26) {
            //capital char
            index = b[i] - 'A';
        }

        if (x[index] > 0)
            x[index] = -1;
    }

    printf("Common characters in '%s' and '%s' are ", a, b);
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (x[i] < 0)
            printf("%c", 'a'+i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count(string a, string b) 
{

   int i,c[26]={0},c1[26]={};

   for(i=0;i<a.length();i++)
   {
        if(97<=a[i]&&a[i]<=123)
        c[a[i]-97]++;
   }
   for(i=0;i<b.length();i++)
   {
       if(97<=b[i]&&b[i]<=123)
        c1[b[i]-97]++;
    } 
    int s=0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        s=s+abs(c[i]+c1[i]-(c[i]-c1[i]));

    }   

    return (s);  
}
```

This is much easier and better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::vector<char>::iterator i = s1.begin(); i != s1.end(); ++i)
{
    if (std::find(s2.begin(), s2.end(), *i) != s2.end())
   {
    dest.push_back(*i);
   }
}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404094/how-do-i-get-characters-common-to-two-vectors-in-c)

Comment: Hmm, but isn't this O(n^2)?

Comment: here's a better algorithm                                                        read string1
read string2
remove all duplicates from string1
for each character in string1
if character exists in string2
thenprint character                                        
end for

Answer (score 0):

C implementation to run in O(n) time and constant space.

```
#define ALPHABETS_COUNT 26 
int commonChars(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int c_count = 0, i; 
    int arr1[ALPHABETS_COUNT] = {0}, arr2[ALPHABETS_COUNT] = {0};

    /* Compute the number of occurances of each character */
    while (*s1) arr1[*s1++-'a'] += 1;
    while (*s2) arr2[*s2++-'a'] += 1;       

    /* Increment count based on match found */
    for(i=0; i<ALPHABETS_COUNT; i++) {
        if(arr1[i] == arr2[i]) c_count += arr1[i];
        else if(arr1[i]>arr2[i] && arr2[i] != 0) c_count += arr2[i];
        else if(arr2[i]>arr1[i] && arr1[i] != 0) c_count += arr1[i];
    }

    return c_count;
```

}

Comment: What would happen when it is other kind of characters like `A` to `Z`? The fact of alphabet doesn't mean only `a` through `z`, but also the uppercases too.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code does not run in O(n^2), it runs in O(nm), where n and m are the length of each string.

You can do it in O(n+m), but not better, since you have to go through each string, at least once, to see if a character is in both.

An example in C++, assuming:

- ASCII characters
- All characters included (letters, numbers, special, spaces, etc...)
- Case sensitive

```
std::vector<char> strIntersect(std::string const&s1, std::string const&s2){

    std::vector<bool> presents(256, false);  //Assuming ASCII
    std::vector<char> intersection;

    for (auto c : s1) {
        presents[c] = true;
    }
    for (auto c : s2) {
        if (presents[c]){
            intersection.push_back(c);
            presents[c] = false;
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> result; 
    std::string s1 = "El perro de San Roque no tiene rabo, porque Ramon Rodriguez se lo ha cortado";
    std::string s2 = "Saint Roque's dog has no tail, because Ramon Rodriguez chopped it off";

    //Expected: "S a i n t   R o q u e s d g h l , b c m r z p"

    result = strIntersect(s1, s2);
    for (auto c : result) {
         std::cout << c << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is a more better version in c++ :
C++ bitset and its application
A bitset is an array of bool but each Boolean value is not stored separately instead bitset optimizes the space such that each bool takes 1 bit space only, so space taken by bitset bs is less than that of bool bs[N] and vector bs(N). However, a limitation of bitset is, N must be known at compile time, i.e., a constant (this limitation is not there with vector and dynamic array)

As bitset stores the same information in compressed manner the operation on bitset are faster than that of array and vector. We can access each bit of bitset individually with help of array indexing operator [] that is bs[3] shows bit at index 3 of bitset bs just like a simple array. Remember bitset starts its indexing backward that is for 10110, 0 are at 0th and 3rd indices whereas 1 are at 1st 2nd and 4th indices.
We can construct a bitset using integer number as well as binary string via constructors which is shown in below code. The size of bitset is fixed at compile time that is, it can’t be changed at runtime.
For more information about bitset visit the site : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-bitset-and-its-application

The code is as follows :

```
    // considering the strings to be of lower case.

    int main()
    {
        string s1,s2;
        cin>>s1>>s2;

        //Declaration for bitset type variables
        bitset<26> b_s1,b_s2;

        // setting the bits in b_s1 for the encountered characters of string s1 
        for(auto& i : s1)
        {
          if(!b_s1[i-'a'])
            b_s1[i-'a'] = 1;
        }

        // setting the bits in b_s2 for the encountered characters of string s2 
        for(auto& i : s2)
        {
          if(!b_s2[i-'a'])
            b_s2[i-'a'] = 1;
        }

       // counting the number of set bits by the "Logical AND"  operation
       // between b_s1 and b_s2
       cout<<(b_s1&b_s2).count(); 

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to initialize and keep an array of 26 elements (numbers for each letter in alphabet). Just fo the following:

1. Using HashMap store letter as a key and integer got the count as a value.
2. Create a Set of characters.
3. Iterate through each string characters, add to the Set from step 2. If add() method returned false, (means that same character already exists in the Set), then add the character to the map and increment the value.

These steps are written considering Java programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Code:**

```
    >>>s1='abbc'    
    >>>s2='abde'
    >>>p=list(set(s1).intersection(set(s2)))
    >>print(p)
    ['a','b']
```

Hope this helps you, Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

can be easily done using the concept of "catching" which is a sub-algorithm of hashing.

Comment: Please be detailed when giving an answer that pretend to be helpful. Your answer raises more doubts than clues. Maybe you should add some examples of what you offer.