# Using JavaScript to find number of common characters

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I am given the task of finding the number of common characters between two strings.  The strings will only be lowercase latin letters and between 1 and 15 characters long.  Placement of the character in the string does not affect this, only the number of times a character occurs in the string.

So for instance aagheyre = trewpuspewqfaw would be

One A in both for one.
Two E's in both for two.
And one r in both for a total of four common characters.

I have been thinking of ways to do this and am coming up short with being able to put all of the puzzle pieces together.

```
    while (orderedArrayOne.length && orderedArrayTwo.length > 0) {
        console.log("it works.");
        for (i = 0; i <= orderedArrayOne.length; i++) {
            console.log("first comparison");
            if (orderedArrayOne[0] === orderedArrayTwo[0]) {
                console.log("first character matches");
                orderedArrayOne.shift();
                console.log(orderedArrayOne + " after push");
                orderedArrayTwo.shift();
                console.log(orderedArrayTwo + " after push");
                characterTicker++;
                console.log(characterTicker);
            } else if ( orderedArrayOne[0] <= orderedArrayTwo[0] ) {
                console.log("first character no longer matches");
                orderedArrayOne.shift();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

If the first index of array one is a character alphabetically lower than the first index of array two then I should be able to remove that character because it is no longer possible to find a match right?

This is what I have so far, can anyone offer some guidance here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding common characters in two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657544/finding-common-characters-in-two-strings)

Comment: @RamblinRose Close, however that is done in C and also I believe in that example the placement of the character matters, they must be in the same slot on the string to count as a duplicate.  In my example as long as it occurs in the string positions isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array `occurrence[26]`, go through each character from first word and increase it's count `occurrence[character.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]++`

Now go through each character from the second word :

```
if (occurrence[character] > 0)
{ 
  common++;
  occurrence[character]--;
}
```